# How do I generate a specific data target for each object with data toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, jekyll

I've created a for loop that displays reviews on my HTML page. On these reviews, there is a button that toggles the full review. Pressing on the toggle button on the first review works fine, however, pressing the button on review nr 2, toggles review nr 1

The problem seems to be, that each review doesn't have a unique data target. So I'll likely have to create some way of generating a new data-target for each review, but I'm not sure how one would go about this. Any ideas?

Thanks for reading this.

```
{% for review in reviews reversed %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
      <!-- horizontal spacing -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-8 ">
    <div class="card text">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="text-primary"> {{ review.name }} </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="float-right text-secondary"> {{ review.pub_date_pretty }} </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating ({{review.avg_rating |floatformat:1 }}) </h5>
        <p class="card-text"> {{review.general_comments}} </p>

      <div class="collapse" id="review">

        <h5 class="card-title"> Interest {{review.interest_rating |floatformat:1 }} </h5>
        <p class="card-text"> {{review.interest}} </p>

        <h5 class="card-title"> Clarity {{review.clarity_rating |floatformat:1 }} </h5>
        <p class="card-text"> {{review.clarity}} </p>

        <h5 class="card-title"> Brevity {{review.brevity_rating |floatformat:1 }} </h5>
        <p class="card-text">  {{review.brevity}} </p>


      </div>

      </div>

      <div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review">
          <div class="row">
          <div> Click to see full review </div>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a number (loop index) to the data-toggle, like: `#review-{% i %}` and the original Id on the div. Check out loop index enumeration for your templating style, which looks like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) in this case.